# "buffered write scheme" for view counter with php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, counter

I read the topic https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated . I understand the algorithm, but I not understand how do that thing in mysql, php.

> Every time a new hit is registered, it is also added to a memory buffer in addition to the expiring cache entry. The buffer itself also expires after a few minutes or after it is filled up to a certain size, whichever happens first. When it expires, everything it has accumulated is written into the database in bulk. They call it a "buffered write scheme".

We use Storage Engine -MEMORY in mysql or maybe better solution with mysql,php.

Can anyone help me how "buffered write scheme" for view counter with php, mysql.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Well it wont go faster than MySQL.

A stored procedure for your query can speed-up the process but database-design is the other half.

Make sure you got one table to count:

user_therad_visit:

```
----------------------------
user_id | thread_id | count
----------------------------
```

Make sure there is an index on or better a two-rows unique index on columns "user_id" and "thread_id".

When a user logs in, read his entire and thread_id and count values and save them in $_SESSION array.

This way you can check by $_SESSION var if the user has already visited the page or not and simply ignore fetching the database if he was already here, this will reduce queries drastically.

Then simply dont forgot to UPDATE your database incase the user has never been on this thread and also directly update your $_SESSION array manually.

With query helper:

INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=VALUES(a)+VALUES(b);

you can simply combine insert into and update, (whatever is needed) into one query also improving performance.

This way a query is only fired when the user enters the thread first time which you have no choice but to write down somewhere and a database is one of the fastest ways to do that.

Aslong as your thread_id and user_id fields are indexed you should be pretty fast with the SELECT query, even with a million rows in the table.